# Panel data with observations per individual per year

Tags: r, fixed, effects

I have a dataset of transactions done by consumers over 5 years. I would like to run a fixed effects regression on this dataset. What would be an appropriate unit of observation in this context? The issue is that each individual has more transactions per year.

If I choose the individual transactions as the unit of observations i get a pooled cross-section, with which I cannot use fixed effects.

Would the correct method be to select one transaction per person per year?

Comment: If you want advice on how to model your data, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. It ll depends on what assumptions you want to make and what type of inference you are trying to do. This isn't a specific programming question that is appropriate for Stack Overflow.